# Show which pages are using a tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to link all the pages that are using a certain tag on another page. Kind of like a link back effect. For instance: page A tags itself with X so page X shows that A has tagged it.

I'm thinking it'd be the opposite of `get_the_tags()`, but I'm not having luck with `has_tags()` at the moment.

Any ideas?

This is what I'm working on now:

```
$lawyersPage = get_page_by_title('Lawyers')->ID;
$lawyers = get_pages( array(
    'child_of'=>$lawyersPage));

foreach($lawyers as $tag){
    if (has_tag('business-law', $tag->ID) {
    echo '
        <a href="'.get_site_url().'/lawyers/'.$tag->post_name.'">
        <li>'.$tag->post_title.'
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right action"></span>
        </li></a>';
```

The tag is `'business-law'` and I'm trying to see if the lawyers in `$lawyers` have used the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a database query:

```
$query=array( 'tag' => 'business-law', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $query );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: When I did that I was getting a lot of bullets but only one real entry. Any idea why? (The code I copied above is within the loop).